# printf of enum classes with inttypes does not work with clang

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, clang

Please consider following minimum example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Foo : uint8_t
{
  John,
  Jane
};

int main()
{
  // does not compile with clang but works fine with gcc
  printf("here is my %" PRIu8 "\n", Foo::John);

  //with cast works fine also with clang
  using T = typename std::underlying_type<Foo>::type;
  printf("here is my %" PRIu8 "\n", T(Foo::John));

  //with cast works fine also with clang
  printf("here is my %" PRIu8 "\n", uint8_t(Foo::John));

  return 0;
}
```

see also [Live Example](https://godbolt.org/g/ZA3aEN)

This example compiles well with gcc, e.g. gcc 4.9.4.
This example does not compile with clang, e.g. clang 3.9.0

Why is it not possible to printf enum classes that are derived from std-inttypes by just using the corresponding printf specifier, in that case `PRIu8` in clang? Is that a clang compiler bug? Or do I miss a detail in the C++ standard?

The compile error is

```
warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has
underlying type 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
```

Comment: Missed the -Werror flag, which we are using in our code bases. But I'm still curious, what clang's problem is

Comment: but it is still an uint8_t isn't it? And the correct format specifier is ´PRIu8´ isn't it? So whats wrong?

Comment: No, it is *not* a `uint8_t` it is a `enum class Foo`. As far as the type system is concerned those are different things (which is a *good* thing).

Answer (score 2):

`enum class Foo` is *not* a `uint8_t` it is an enumeration that just happens to use `uint8_t` as its underlying representation. If you want it to be converted to `uint8_t`, use a `static_cast`.

The type system is actually trying to help you here - the types *are* different (even if convertible).